# mysql sum all columns and insert into a table

Tags: mysql

I am practicing with some queries, there is a table with n number of columns, and I would like to calculate the sum of all columns.

I have two questions
1) 
`SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ',GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(',c.COLUMN_NAME,')') SEPARATOR ', '),') FROM CashPOSDB.tmInv "') as Query FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c WHERE table_schema = 'CashPOSDB' and TABLE_NAME='tmInv' AND c.COLUMN_NAME<>'date' and c.COLUMN_NAME<> 'id';`

> This query supposed to get a select statement of the sum of all columns, but I am not sure why its not returning all the columns, it only get around half of the columns around 70 of them. Is there anyways I can fix that?

2)

> is there anyways I can simply get the sum of all columns and insert that into a table that has the same structure.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, group_concat is truncated to 1024 characters.

You can increase that limit by doing e.g.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000;
```

before your query.